# Alter the column type over several tables

Tags: postgresql

In a PostgreSQL db I'm working on, half of the tables have one particular column, always named the same, that is of type varchar(5). The size became a bit too restricting and I want to change it to varchar(10).

The number of tables in my particular case is actually very manageable to do it by hand. But I was wondering how one could script this with a query for larger dbs. It generally should be possible in just a few steps.

1. Identify all the tables in the schema, then (?) filter by condition if column present.
2. Create ALTER TABLE statements for each table found

I have some idea about how to write a query that identifies all tables in the schema. But I wouldn't know how to filter them. And if I didn't filter them, I assume the generated alter table statements would break.

Would be great if someone could share their knowledge on this.

Comment: `select table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns where table_catalog = 'postgres' and table_schema = 'public' and column_name = 'foo'` ?

Comment: Naturally, I replaced 'foo' with the respective column name. But this query doesn't return anything for me.

Comment: OK, replaced 'postgres' with the name of the db, that gives me the correct tables now. Now let's see if I can figure out how to build the alter table statement based on that...

Comment: You might also have to change the schema if your tables aren't in the public schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Abelisto for providing some guidance. Eventually, this is how I did it.

First, I created a query that in turn creates the `ALTER TABLE` statements. `MyDB` and `MyColumn` need to reflect actual values.

```
SELECT 
   'ALTER TABLE '||columns.table_name||' ALTER COLUMN '||MyColumn||' TYPE varchar(20);'
FROM 
   information_schema.columns
WHERE 
  columns.table_catalog = 'MyDB' AND 
  columns.table_schema = 'public' AND 
  columns.column_name = 'MyColumn';
```

Then it was just a matter of executing the output as a new query. All done.